# Use ServiceBus in Azure Functions from Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I would like to write to a service bus queue from Azure Function. But the `ServiceBus` configuration doesn't work.

I have the following dependencies:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 3.0.0-beta5
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.13

Could anyone please help me how to connect to the service bus?

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace HttpTrigger
{
    public static class RegisterDevice
    {
        [FunctionName("RegisterDevice")]
        public static IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [ServiceBus("deviceupdates", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ICollector<string> outputSbMsg,
            TraceWriter log)
        {

        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        outputSbMsg.Add(name);

        return name != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
             : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }
}
```

}

local.settings.json (updated)

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "ServiceBusConnection":"SecretConnectionString"
  }
}
```

Comment: In this page, they are using ServiceBusTrigger for the function instead of ServiceBus. Have you tried it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus

Comment: ServiceBusTrigger is used to receive event not to send event

Comment: Do you have any error? Have you tried to send a message to the queue using the same connectionstring outside of a function ???

Comment: @Thomas yh. sending a message to the queue work. I tried csx (online editor) and it works. I would like to use VS because of git. If I publish the above code and execute on Azure, there is a Status: 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

Put your `QueueConnectionString` under `Values` not `ConnectionStrings`.

Comment: thanks. I fixed the local.settings.json as you said. But it still doesn't work. If I deploy the function to AZ, how is the connection string passed to the function? How do I set it on Azure`?

Comment: You need to add it in Application settings in the portal